# Optimizing a query that performs worse on a smaller dataset

Tags: mysql, join, optimization

I am trying to run this query. The * is just for simplification, I'm selecting ~10 specific fields for some calculations.

```
SELECT * FROM `orders`
    LEFT JOIN `orders_processed` ON `orders_processed`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `returns` ON
        `orders_processed`.`date_id`=`returns`.`date_id`
        AND `orders_processed`.`product_id`=`returns`.`product_id`
        AND `orders_processed`.`variant_id`=`returns`.`variant_id`
WHERE `orders`.`date_id` BETWEEN @from AND @to
```

Where date_id is a date in the format '%Y%m%d' (e.g. 20150501), is not unique (multiple rows have the same date_ids), `orders` and `returns` have ~200k rows each, `orders_processed` has ~400k.
I'm running this query with `@from := 20140505`, `@to := 20150505` and it stalls. I'm assuming it's because of

```
`orders_processed`.`date_id`=`returns`.`date_id`
```

since when I change it to

```
`orders_processed`.`order_id`=`returns`.`order_id`
```

it runs in a split second. However, the calculation result changes and I do not want that. Is there any way to change this part of the join into something more efficient?

Also, it might be worth mentioning that it runs fine on an identical, just slightly bigger database (same schema, just updated with new data).

The EXPLAIN for query on the smaller database:

```
select_type |   table   | table type | possible_keys | key     |key_len| ref     | rows | extra
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SIMPLE  |   orders  |    range   |     date_id   | date_id |   5   | null    |89264 | Using where; Using index
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SIMPLE  |o_processed|    ref     | uni,order_id  |   uni   |   4   |orders.id|   1  | null
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SIMPLE|returns|ref|date_id,returns_ibfk_1,returns_ibfk_5|returns_ibfk_1|3|orders_processed.variant_id|5|Using where
```

The explain result for the bigger database is identical except for the 'rows' for `orders`, it's 95020.

The CREATE TABLEs (simplified, removed irrelevant columns)

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `customer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `date_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipping` decimal(10,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY (`date_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `ref_order_id`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `orders_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`date_id`) REFERENCES `cr_calendar` (`date_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_processed` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `date_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `product_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `variant_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `price` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `quantity` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
    `updated_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `uni`(`order_id`,`product_id`,`variant_id`,`price`),
    KEY(`order_id`),
    KEY(`product_id`),
    KEY(`date_id`),
    KEY(`quantity`),
    KEY(`variant_id`),
    KEY(`updated_on`),
    CONSTRAINT `orders_processed_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `orders_processed_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `ref_order_id`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `orders_processed_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`date_id`) REFERENCES `calendar`(`date_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `returns` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `customer_id` int(8) unsigned not null default 0,
    `product_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `variant_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `date_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `refund` decimal(10,2) unsigned DEFAULT '0.00',
    `reason` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `updated_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `uni`(`order_id`,`product_id`,`variant_id`,`reason`),
    KEY(`date_id`),
    KEY(`reason`),
    KEY(`updated_on`),
    CONSTRAINT `returns_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `returns_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`reason`) REFERENCES `ref_reasons` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `returns_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `ref_order_id` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `returns_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`variant_id`) REFERENCES `variants`(`variant_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: You should check and/or post results of [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) for the query on both databases. It will tell you the difference. If you post CREATE TABLEs also, we can tell you more.

Comment: Please show the `SELECT` part as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're joining `returns` on the **date and the type of item only**, creating a semi-cartesian product. E.g. If you have 100 orders for item A, and 100 returns of item A, on the same day, you'll return `100 x 100 = 10,000 rows`, with every return joined to every order. Is this what you want?

In terms of performance, the difference between your two databases may be that the data in the other database gives a smaller results set. E.g. It also has 100 orders for item A and 100 returns of item A but they're spread out over two days giving `(50 x 50) + (50 x 50) = 5,000` (same number of source rows but query results are half as many rows).

Comment: I would join on orders_processed.order_id = returns.order_id (it makes more sense) but I was not the one who wrote the query and I'm just porting it / trying to make it work on a different database. If I do a join on order_id, the result is different from the one I get from a semi-cartesian product. Some of the calculations are complex and I don't want to mess with the data so I would be really grateful for any suggestions on how to optimize this.

Comment: I understand but I'd encourage you to question if this is right; there are not many instances where the results of this query would provide valid information so it seems fairly likely that this was an error and should be fixed. In terms of optimization the difficulty will be that the size of the results set can vary dramatically based on the join, not just the number of rows/size of data.